# Modal Foundation via URL

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Preciso abrir um modal `zurb-foundation` via `URL`. Por exemplo http://sistema.com.br/agenda/#modal99

Segue o código:

**Html:**

```
<a href="#modal99">Show Modal</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $('#modal99').foundation('open');
```

O código não abre o modal.

Obs: Não posso usar `<a data-open="modal99">Show Modal</a>`.
E nem `<a id="modal99">Show Modal</a>`.
Tem que ser via `href`.

Comment: No Javascript tenta `$('#modal99').foundation('reveal', 'open');`

Comment: Ainda não abre @LucasCosta

Comment: Fiz um fiddle pegando o evento click no link e abrindo um modal e funcionou..é isso o que precisa? https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/sqyd9xbc/1/

Comment: @LucasCosta não posso usar `id="modal99"` como citei na observação. Tem que ser via `href`.

Comment: Não tem como apontar um href e mudar a forma do modal. Não sei porque você precisa fazer dessa forma, mas uma solução é usar o seletor `href` no JQquery e abrir o modal, mais ou menos assim: `$("[href='#modal99']")`: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/sqyd9xbc/2/

Comment: Seu exemplo funciona, mas queria algo assim. var url = document.URL.split('#');
    var modalUrl = (url[url.length - 1]);
    
    $('#modal' + modalUrl).foundation('open');

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47768/discussion-between-eduardo-santos-and-lucas-costa).

Comment: A solução mais eficaz encontrada é utilizar o array do fullcalendar. Que seria: eventClick: function (event) {

                        var key = event._id;

                        $('#modal' + key).foundation('open');

                    }